# jquery.ajax post get issue

Tags: php, jquery

I am new to studying jquery.ajax. Through some tutorials,  I tried some code by myself, but I met some trouble. So I ask for help.

I tried to do this: open `a.php`, send html data from `div#send` to `b.php`, then return the data and show in `div#result`.

**`a.php`**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script language="javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function () {      
var params = "value=" + $('#send').text();   
$.ajax({        
     url:'b.php',        
     type:'post',                 
     dataType:'html',            
     data:params,                
     success:data     
     }); 
function data (html) {   
var str=html.send;   
alert(html);
$("#result").html(str); 
} 
}); 
</script>
<body>
<div id="result"></div>// I need return 'this is an apple.'
<div id="send">apple</div>
```

**`b.php`**

```
<?php
echo 'This is an '.$_REQUEST['value'].'.'; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To return datas from b.php, you have to do an `echo`

Comment: In the function data, do a `alert(html);`, to see if datas are successfuly returned.

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending any valid parameters with the ajax request. If you want the textual contents of `#send` you need to use:

```
$('#send').text();
```

Although that only gives you a string, so it would have to be:

```
var params = "value=" + $('#send').text();
```

Apart from that, `$_REQUEST` is an array, so you have to use something like `$_REQUEST['value']`

A third point is that your success function is too complicated and wrong (`html.send` does not exist), it could just be:

```
success: function(msg){
  $("#result").html(msg);
}
```

Comment: @Xavinou, thanks, I changed my code with yours, but I can get a  `alert` box : `this is a apple`, not in `div#result`.

Comment: @yuli chika  : $("#result").html(html);

Comment: @yuli chika Yes, I already noticed that your success function was not correct so I modified my answer.